# Can I use logs and stumps as driveway fill?

Tags: construction, landscaping, driveway, grading, excavation

I am making a drive in a lot with some low spots. I am curious if anyone has insight or experience using trees cut from a lot as fill for a driveway, to make a level drive.

The lot is all relatively flat bedrock, with some ledge cavities a couple feet deep, that is where the logs might be used to as fill, thinking perhaps they can can rot, but won't be able to sink into the earth or wash away.

Thanks for any thoughts!

Comment: "Corduroy" roads were a thing. What is the climate (aka how fast will they rot)?

Comment: Corduroy roads are on the surface and were very temporary. Wood is just a bad idea, and even _organic soil_ should be removed. This is standard practice for good reason.

Comment: They won't sink into the earth, but _you_ will sink into _them_. Don't do it.

Answer (score 17):

Bad idea - as it rots, it will become spongy and sink as you drive on it, and become very un-level.

Comment: Thanks @Ecnerwal, good point, I was thinking that, I should have mentioned the lot is all bedrock, with cavities in the ledge, that is where I am considering to use fill, definitely will decompose and squish a bit, but it's all bedrock, so I am thinking it can't go far, and if needed I will had more rip rap and gravel on top.

Comment: Sounds more like a modern art project than a DIY question.  A living breathing driveway to reflect the ups and downs of rural life?

Comment: @DubD Stick to hard fill, or learn a lesson the hard way - your choice. A pit full of rotten wood will happily leave you sunk up to your axles, calling a tow truck, and hiring an excavator to dig out the glop and put in the fill you should have used from the start.

Comment: @DubD you wrote these pits are so deep that the decomposed material cannot wash away.  Right?  That's pretty deep?   You really want your vehicles, and your visitors', and hopefully not but maybe an ambulance or fire truck, to be driving through your kitchen sponge paving job if they might sink up to their axles?

Comment: We bought some property with a huge wood dump on the edge of it. They've been dumping wood there for 60 years.  The "ground" there is spongy as all getout.  You can't even walk on it.  I can't mow it, the garden tractor sinks right in.

Comment: Totally see what yall are saying, for sure it will become an issue. Even with rip rap and gravel over, the spaces between, when it fills those voids, it will become mucky and surely sink then require more fill. Thank yall for helping me envision this. You are right on the art as well, there will be a maker shop on the lot, woodwork, stained glass, art and such! I'm stoked that I signed up and asked a Q here, thx again!

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica buy some mushroom spawn and spread it around that part.... ;^)

Comment: Why not @Harper-ReinstateMonica, if only I could find the good kind.